# SQL Sum & Count with Multiple Conditions and Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables as below:

```
Cust_table columns: C_ID, C_Country
Store_table columns: S_ID, S_Name, S_Country
Tran_table columns: C_ID, S_ID, S_Type, Spending
```

Cust_table

```
C_ID   C_Country
999    CN
888    TW
```

Store_table

```
S_ID   S_Name   S_Country
123    ABC      CN
456    DEF      JP
789    GHI      CN
```

Tran_table

```
C_ID   S_ID   S_Type   Spending
999    123    ML       106
888    123    ML       642
888    456    Outlet   364
888    789    ML       422
999    456    ML       263
```

Questions:
Find out the number of local and non-local customers and their respective spending in each store, order by S_country and S_Type. (S_Country=C_Country to define local and non-local customer & spending)

ANS required fields: S_Country,S_ID,S_Name,No_Local,Local_Spending, No_NonLocal,NonLocal_Speding

Expected Outcome

```
S_Country S_ID  S_Name  No_Local Local_Speding No_NonLocal NonLocal_Spending
CN        123   ABC     1        106           1           642
CN        789   GHI     0        0             1           422
JP        456   DEF     0        0             2           627
```

My initial thought is to use count/countif(?) to find out the number of local and non-local spending, sum for total spending. 
But I don't know how to include all conditions in one query. 
Could anyone please help? Thank you.

So far, I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_table.S_Country, 
store_table.store_ID,
Store_table.store_name,
SUM (spending)

FROM store_table, tran_table

WHERE Store_table.store_ID=tran_table.store_ID;
```

Comment: Please add table structure dummy values and expected result

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be nice if you try it yourself first and post the code here if its not working and post a sample data and desired output as well.

Comment: does s_type filed has the country name either s_country name /c_country depending on whether it is local/non local customer ?

Comment: It will be great if you can post some data for these tables and the required result that you are expecting to see ...else we might interpret this differently

Comment: sorry guys, I've added the table and expected outcome. S_country and C_country are corresponding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have no matching transaction for a store, so you have to use outer joins.

Use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to remove undesired (non-)local values:

```
SELECT S_Country,
       S_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S_Country =  C_Country THEN 1        END) AS No_Local,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S_Country =  C_Country THEN Spending END) AS Local_Spending,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S_Country <> C_Country THEN 1        END) AS No_NonLocal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN S_Country <> C_Country THEN Spending END) AS NonLocal_Spending
FROM Store_table
LEFT JOIN Tran_table USING (S_ID)
LEFT JOIN Cust_table USING (C_ID)
GROUP BY S_ID;
```